# How to use GDB to trace compiled JDK9 Hotspot?

Tags: c++, jvm, java, java-9

Some people use NetBeans to trace and debug JDK9. However, I have to use GDB to trace source code and see the control flow of JDK/Hotspot code since I use `ssh` to access source code on the server, and I cannot use GUI/IDE.

I follow Buildme.md from JDK official document to configure JDK9,

`bash ./configure --with-debug-level=slowdebug --with-target-bits=64 --disable-warnings-as-errors`

Then,

`make all`

I get my customized `debug` version:

```
/images/jdk/bin/java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-adhoc.xfwu.9dev)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-adhoc.xfwu.9dev, mixed mode)
```

In the directory: `9jdk/hotspot`:

```
.
├── make
│   ├── copy
│   ├── gensrc
│   ├── ide
│   ├── lib
│   ├── mapfiles
│   │   ├── libjsig
│   │   ├── libjvm_db
│   │   ├── libjvm_dtrace
│   │   └── libsaproc
│   ├── src
│   │   └── classes
│   ├── symbols
│   └── test
├── src
│   ├── cpu
│   │   ├── aarch64
│   │   ├── arm
│   │   ├── ppc
│   │   ├── s390
│   │   ├── sparc
│   │   ├── x86
│   │   └── zero
│   ├── jdk.aot
│   │   ├── share
│   │   └── unix
│   ├── jdk.hotspot.agent
│   │   ├── doc
│   │   ├── linux
│   │   ├── macosx
│   │   ├── scripts
│   │   ├── share
│   │   ├── solaris
│   │   ├── test
│   │   └── windows
│   ├── jdk.internal.vm.ci
│   │   └── share
│   ├── jdk.internal.vm.compiler
│   │   └── share
│   ├── os
│   │   ├── aix
│   │   ├── bsd
│   │   ├── linux
│   │   ├── posix
│   │   ├── solaris
│   │   └── windows
│   ├── os_cpu
│   │   ├── aix_ppc
│   │   ├── bsd_x86
│   │   ├── bsd_zero
│   │   ├── linux_aarch64
│   │   ├── linux_arm
│   │   ├── linux_ppc
│   │   ├── linux_s390
│   │   ├── linux_sparc
│   │   ├── linux_x86
│   │   ├── linux_zero
│   │   ├── solaris_sparc
│   │   ├── solaris_x86
│   │   └── windows_x86
│   └── share
│       ├── tools
│       └── vm
└── test
    ├── compiler
    │   ├── aot
    │   ├── arguments
    │   ├── arraycopy
    │   ├── c1
    │   ├── c2
    │   ├── calls
    │   ├── ciReplay
    │   ├── classUnloading
    │   ├── codecache
    │   ├── codegen
    │   ├── compilercontrol
    │   ├── controldependency
    │   ├── cpuflags
    │   ├── debug
    │   ├── dependencies
    │   ├── eliminateAutobox
    │   ├── escapeAnalysis
    │   ├── exceptions
    │   ├── floatingpoint
    │   ├── gcbarriers
    │   ├── inlining
    │   ├── integerArithmetic
    │   ├── interpreter
    │   ├── intrinsics
    │   ├── jsr292
    │   ├── jvmci
    │   ├── linkage
    │   ├── loopopts
    │   ├── macronodes
    │   ├── membars
    │   ├── memoryinitialization
    │   ├── onSpinWait
    │   ├── oracle
    │   ├── osr
    │   ├── patches
    │   ├── print
    │   ├── profiling
    │   ├── rangechecks
    │   ├── reflection
    │   ├── regalloc
    │   ├── relocations
    │   ├── rtm
    │   ├── runtime
    │   ├── stable
    │   ├── startup
    │   ├── stringopts
    │   ├── testlibrary
    │   ├── tiered
    │   ├── types
    │   ├── uncommontrap
    │   ├── unsafe
    │   ├── vectorization
    │   └── whitebox
    ├── gc
    │   ├── arguments
    │   ├── class_unloading
    │   ├── cms
    │   ├── CondCardMark
    │   ├── ergonomics
    │   ├── g1
    │   ├── logging
    │   ├── metaspace
    │   ├── parallel
    │   ├── serial
    │   ├── startup_warnings
    │   ├── stress
    │   ├── survivorAlignment
    │   ├── testlibrary
    │   └── whitebox
    ├── native
    │   ├── classfile
    │   ├── code
    │   ├── gc
    │   ├── logging
    │   ├── memory
    │   ├── oops
    │   ├── runtime
    │   └── utilities
    ├── native_sanity
    ├── runtime
    │   ├── 6294277
    │   ├── 6626217
    │   ├── 6819213
    │   ├── 6981737
    │   ├── 7100935
    │   ├── 7116786
    │   ├── 7158988
    │   ├── 7160757
    │   ├── 7162488
    │   ├── 7167069
    │   ├── 8007320
    │   ├── 8007475
    │   ├── 8010389
    │   ├── 8024804
    │   ├── 8026365
    │   ├── 8026394
    │   ├── Annotations
    │   ├── BadObjectClass
    │   ├── BoolReturn
    │   ├── BootClassAppendProp
    │   ├── CDSCompressedKPtrs
    │   ├── ClassFile
    │   ├── classFileParserBug
    │   ├── ClassResolutionFail
    │   ├── ClassUnload
    │   ├── CommandLine
    │   ├── CompactStrings
    │   ├── CompressedOops
    │   ├── constantPool
    │   ├── ConstantPool
    │   ├── contended
    │   ├── defineAnonClass
    │   ├── duplAttributes
    │   ├── EnclosingMethodAttr
    │   ├── ErrorHandling
    │   ├── execstack
    │   ├── Final
    │   ├── finalStatic
    │   ├── getSysPackage
    │   ├── handlerInTry
    │   ├── InternalApi
    │   ├── interned
    │   ├── invokedynamic
    │   ├── jni
    │   ├── jsig
    │   ├── lambda-features
    │   ├── libadimalloc.solaris.sparc
    │   ├── LoadClass
    │   ├── LocalLong
    │   ├── LocalVariableTable
    │   ├── logging
    │   ├── memory
    │   ├── Metaspace
    │   ├── MinimalVM
    │   ├── MirrorFrame
    │   ├── modules
    │   ├── NMT
    │   ├── os
    │   ├── PerfMemDestroy
    │   ├── RedefineObject
    │   ├── RedefineTests
    │   ├── reflect
    │   ├── ReservedStack
    │   ├── Safepoint
    │   ├── SameObject
    │   ├── SelectionResolution
    │   ├── SharedArchiveFile
    │   ├── StackGuardPages
    │   ├── stackMapCheck
    │   ├── testlibrary
    │   ├── Thread
    │   ├── ThreadSignalMask
    │   ├── Throwable
    │   ├── TransitiveOverrideCFV50
    │   ├── Unsafe
    │   ├── verifier
    │   ├── whitebox
    │   └── XCheckJniJsig
    ├── sanity
    │   └── MismatchedWhiteBox
    ├── serviceability
    │   ├── 7170638
    │   ├── attach
    │   ├── dcmd
    │   ├── jdwp
    │   ├── jvmti
    │   ├── logging
    │   ├── sa
    │   ├── threads
    │   └── tmtools
    ├── testlibrary
    │   ├── ctw
    │   ├── jittester
    │   └── jvmti
    └── testlibrary_tests
        ├── ctw
        └── whitebox
```

### I don't know how to use GDB to trace JDK9 Hotspot code.

For example how to trace a simple HelloWorld.java code and go through all Hotspot code.

```
public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Prints "Hello, World" in the terminal window.
      System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
}
```

I want to learn the flow of Hotspot code based on STEP BY STEP way.

Although I can read the `static` source code and generate control flow graph for me to understand, but that is not enough for me to develop.

`/9dev/jdk/test/sun/management/jmxremote/bootstrap/launcher.c`

[image]

---

I know basic GDB command

```
start
    start gcc 

list
    enter to show 10 more lines

step
    step into and go through

print [var]
    variable name
    p = print

next
    step over

x [var]
    addr: raw var
    examine abbr.

watch  [var]
rwatch
info watch
info break

cont
    continue until break point

break #line 

bt
    backtrace
frame #
    change context and subrounte and rounte

set var sum=23
    set a varible inside and change the variable instantly

quit
exit gdb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### configure and make

configure parameters

`bash ./configure --with-target-bits=64 --with-debug-level=slowdebug --disable-warnings-as-errors --with-native-debug-symbols=internal`

`make clean`

`make all`

#### version

`xfwu:~/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/jdk/bin$./java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (slowdebug build 9-internal+0-adhoc.xfwu.9jdk)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (slowdebug build 9-internal+0-adhoc.xfwu.9jdk, mixed mode)`

### gdb

`xfwu:~/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/jdk/bin$gdb --args java ~/sanboxJDK/9jdk/javaPrj/HelloWorld`

Answer (score 1):

You can run your debug session in gdb using the gdbserver remote debugging.
For reference:

- https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/04/gdbserver-example

**Note:** You will need to run two separate instances of remote ssh sessions, where in one of the session you will run gdbserver and from the other session you will be running the gdb client for debugging JVM code.

Comment: Sorry, this may not solve my problem. My problem is how to debug JVM code.

Comment: I am sorry@skytree. With the example quoted above it seems you are trying to debug C/C++ source code of the OpenJDK JVM or do you want to debug Java Code it is not very clear.

Comment: I am trying to debug C/C++ source code of the OpenJDK JVM.

Comment: You can run the OpenJDK JVM with gdbserver from one ssh session, then connect to gdbserver from another ssh session using gdb.